# To extract a value from one http request and pass to another http request

Tags: performance, testing, load, jmeter

my issue is i have to extract "key" from that request and pass to another http request, how can i do that? what will be the steps, please guide

[image]

Comment: Was the key generated by the previous request?

Answer (score 0):

I have used "regular expression extractor" and it has resolved my issue

Comment: and i do not know why, again problem is arriving nothing is arriving in regular expression extractor now